# Programmatically invoke browser in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Need to show browser through my application.
My application should go in background and browser should come in foreground.

```
int moduleHandle =
        CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_browser_daemon");
    if (moduleHandle > 0)
    {
        // Use the default browser application descriptor as the
        // model descriptor.
        ApplicationDescriptor[] browserDescriptors =
            CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(moduleHandle);

        // Create the new application descriptor.
        String[] args = {"url", url, null};

        // Turn off auto restart (the original descriptor has it
        // turned on) so we don't end up in a never ending loop of
        // restarting the browser.
        int flags = browserDescriptors[0].getFlags() ^
             ApplicationDescriptor.FLAG_AUTO_RESTART;
        ApplicationDescriptor newDescriptor =
            new ApplicationDescriptor
            (
                browserDescriptors[0],
                "BrowserPS",
                 args,
                 null,
                 -1,
                 null,
                 -1,
                 flags
            );

        // Run the application.
        try
        {
            ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().
                runApplication(newDescriptor);
        }
        catch (ApplicationManagerException ame)
        {
            System.err.println(ame.toString());
        }
    }
```

This is my code it's working fine in simulator, but not on actual device.
any help.

Comment: Have you looked at the `net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser` and `net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.BrowserSession` classes yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
  BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
  browserSession.displayPage(URL);
```